# Calling a Async task from a service in android

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, android-service

Hello everybody I need help in calling a Asynctask from service

There is an Asynctask in my Main class extends with Fragment I want to call this Asynctask for every periodic interval time or when ever next update needed for this case I am thinking to implement services class in my application can any one guide me how can I achieve this

Thanks in Advance

Comment: You can use handler for it.

Comment: Hi Anshul, can you give any example implementing handler on button click

Comment: From the Docs: `A Service is an application component that can perform long-running operations in the background and does not provide a user interface. Another application component can start a service and it will continue to run in the background even if the user switches to another application. ` Why reinvent the wheel?

Answer (score 1):

Create a handler inside `onCreate` like this :

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
        }
    }, SPLASH_TIME_OUT);
```

here SPLASH_TIME_OUT is an integer which tells time to call this method again and again.

```
private static int SPLASH_TIME_OUT = 1500;
```